# Schema Browser is not available in sql developer context menu - version 3.3.20.10

Tags: schema, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am not able to see the Schema Browser command in the context menu of Sql Developer in my Ora Sql Developer tool (right click of  connectionname). How to enable or view the schema - tables, functions, procedures etc- in the Sql Developer version 3.3.20.10.

When i checked in another later version  say 4.1. , its available .

But my machine is having the old version of Sql developer. I hope, there must be a way to achieve the schema browser functionality in the old version.
How to enable it.

Comment: There is no version 3.3

Comment: i wrote this post when version 3.1 or version 3.2 would have been around - did you disable any features? https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/02/sql-developer-trick-dropdown-vs-tree/

Comment: No, inside our customer network we dont have any access to update / install any s/ws. so, disabling a feature of the installed s/w never arises!

Comment: in the UI, there's a menu option in v3 that lets you turn off features. in newer versions it's Tools - Features. In that version it may be called something else